# imagesc() in Matlab not showing equal axis

Tags: image, matlab, plot, scale, axis

I use the following lines of code to plot the images:

```
for t=1:subplotCol
    subplot(subplotRow,subplotCol,t)
    imagesc([1 100],[1 100],c(:,:,nStep*t));
    colorbar
    xlabel('X-axis')
    ylabel('Y-axis')
    title(['Concentration profile at t_{',num2str(nStep*t),'}'])

    subplot(subplotRow,subplotCol,subplotCol+t)
    hold on;
    plot(distance,gamma(:,1,t),'-ob');
    plot(distance,gamma(:,2,t),'-or');
    plot(distance,gamma(:,3,t),'-og');
    xlabel('h');ylabel('\gamma (h)');
    legend(['\Theta = ',num2str(theta(1))],...
        ['\Theta = ',num2str(theta(2))],['\Theta = ',num2str(theta(3))]);
end
```

I get the following subplot with images:

[image]

As you can see the images in first row are now scaled equally on X and Y axis (Y axis is longer than the X-axis) even though the size of the image matrix is 100x100 for each image on first row.

Can someone help with how to make images in first row look like squares than rectangles which I get currently. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `dataAspectRatio` properties of the axes, and set it to `[1 1 1]`

```
%# create a test image
imagesc(1:10,1:10,rand(10))
```

[image]

```
%# you should use the handle returned by subplot
%# instead of gca
set(gca,'dataAspectRatio',[1 1 1])
```

[image]

Comment: Jonas: Thanks for your answer. Using your suggested command gives one image on the subplot but then it gives an error which says `??? Error using ==> set
There is no 'dataAspectRatio' property in the
'image' class.`. I am not sure why it does after the first image but not for the first image itself. Would you know why?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. I used the handle from imagesc() rather than from the subplot as you suggested. One follow up question: the images are now squares, but they are much smaller in size than the ones in 2nd row. You can look in the question update to see the relative sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use the command `axis equal`

Regarding the size of different objects, you can set the exact position of each axes on the figure, for example for the first one use:
`subplot(2,2,1); set(gca,'Position',[0.05 0.05 0.4 0.4])`

Comment: Hi. Using `set(gca,'Position',[0.05 0.05 0.4 0.4])` overlaps the images from 1st row with the 1st image of the 2nd row. In other words the setting of the image positions are changed due to overlapping of images.